# How Do I Add A Second To A DateTime and Then Check The Difference PHP?

Tags: php

Just wondering how I can make 2 UTC DateTime objects. Add 1 second to one of them. And then compare them and know that one of them is 1 second in the future.

I have been trying this...

```
<?php

$datetime1 = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$datetime2 = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));

$datetime2 = $datetime2->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 1 . 'M'));


$diff=$datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
echo $diff->format('%d days, %m month, %y years, %m minutes, %s seconds');
```

> Expected : 0 days, 0 month, 0 years, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
>
> Actual   : 0 days, 0 month, 0 years, 0 minutes, 0 seconds

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You make three mistakes:

1) youl should construct $datetime2 from datetime1 to be sure you start with exactly the same time.

```
$datetime1 = new \DateTime("now", new \DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$datetime2 = new \DateTime('@'.$datetime1->getTimestamp());
```

2) to add one second use 'S' instead of 'M' (that stands for minute)

```
$datetime2 = $datetime2->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 1 . 'S'));
```

3) the format for minute in dateInterval is %i and not %m

```
$diff=$datetime1->diff($datetime2); 
echo $diff->format('%d days, %m month, %y years, %i minutes, %s seconds');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
$datetime2 = $datetime2->add(new DateInterval('PT' . 1 . 'S'));
```

and you'll have:

```
0 days, 0 month, 0 years, 0 minutes, 1 seconds
```

See in https://ideone.com/ASGluQ